# Push back numbers in a deque in c++

Tags: c++, deque

I've got a deque in c++ and I want to push back to it numbers from 1 to 17. I wrote the following code:
string Result;

```
string Result;          

ostringstream convert;   

for(int i=1; i< 18; i++){

    convert >> i;      
    Result = convert.str(); 
    temp.push_back(Result);   
}

cout <<"temp at_"<< temp.at(16) << endl;
```

The problem is that temp.at(16) prints with `cout: 1234567891011121314151617` and `not 17`, how is it possible to add every time just the current i?

Edit: the above code works:

```
string Result;          
ostringstream convert;   
for(int i=1; i< 18; i++){

            convert.str(std::string());
    convert << i;      
        Result = convert.str(); 
    temp.push_back(Result);   
}

cout <<"temp at_"<< temp.at(16) << endl;
```

Comment: So, what is `Result`, and what is the type of `convert`?

Comment: You might start by adding `std::cout << Result << '\n';` before the `push_back` so you can see what you're really pushing....  The problem's going to be with `convert`, not the `deque`.

Comment: dont assign to convert: `convert = i;`, use: `convert << i;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you are not clearing your `converter`,

```
 1234567891011121314151617
```

are all your integers you iterated

Assuming, convert is:

```
std::stringstream convert;
```

you can clear it before each use using:

```
convert.str(std::string());
convert << i;
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suspect the problem lies in `convert << i`. If it works how I think it does, you're appending numbers in a string-like fashion onto that variable, and it just keeps accumulating until it gets that ridiculously long string you received.

Try `convert = i;`

Answer (score 1):

The << operator inserts all 'i's to the stream. So at the end you will get all the numbers yo